# Cannot get table cell value

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table, cell

I want to add a row of data to the end of a table on click of a button. I, however want to check the last table row for incomplete entry before I add any new row at the bottom so that I will not be submitting blank rows or invalid data.

So, far, all attempts to get the value of a given cell using innerHtml, innerText, etc. have failed. I have even tried to change the colour of the cell to confirm I am referring to the correct cell object. I have checked this forum and other sites, but cannot find out how to get the cells content.

```
 <table id="tblTimePlaces" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:150px">Date</th>
      <th style="width:150px">Location</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (TimesPlacesViewModel timeplace in Model.TimesPlaces)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@timeplace.IncidentDate</td>
        <td>@timeplace.IncidentLocation</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="RemoveTP(this)" /></td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="inDt"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" id="inPl" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnAddTimePlace" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Start of my btnAddTimePlace onClick function...

```
$('#btnAddTimePlace').click(function () {
var table = $("#tblTimePlaces")[0];
var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];

for( i = 0; i < lastRow.cells.length -1; i++) {
  cell = lastRow.cells[i];
  cell.style.color='blue';
    alert(cell.innerText);
} .......
```

What I will like to achieve is that the date and location columns of the last row should be checked for valid entries before I get to insert another row. If either column is empty or invalid(I can sort out the validation aspect of each column), I will issue a return false, and not proceed with the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get value of inputs like this.

```
<script>
    $('#btnAddTimePlace').click(function () {
        var table = $("#tblTimePlaces")[0];
        var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
        var inputs = $(lastRow).find("input").not("input[type=button]");
        for( i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var v = $(inputs[i]).val(); // this is value of input
            alert(v);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with Vanilla JavaScript (plain JavaScript) like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tblTimePlaces');
var lastRow = [].slice.call(table.rows).pop(); 
/* to get last row (converting HTMLCollection to array and getting last 
   element of array with pop() function )*/


for(var i=0; i < lastRow.children.length; i++) {
    var textPut = lastRow.children[i].firstChild;
    textPut.style.color='blue';
}
```